# Generic field.html.twig template for a custom Entity

Tags: theming, entities

I have a custom Entity called custom_entity, along with a custom module which provides twig templates for my bundles and their fields.

How can I define a generic/base field template for all fields created under custom_entity?

For a specific field I could create the template:

```
field--custom-entity--field-my-field.html.twig
```

But I'm looking to do something more general, like:

```
field--custom-entity.twig
```

Where all my fields created on a custom_entity use this base template.

I don't want to modify field.html.twig in the theme. I want this template to only apply to my entity and its bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Add your own theme suggestion:

*mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_field_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  // place the least specific suggestion at the beginning of the array  
  array_unshift($suggestions, 'field__' . $element['#entity_type']);

}
```

Comment: This worked if I implemented hook_theme in my custom module and pointed to the `field__custom_entity` template. However, then none of the fields would use their overridden field templates.

For example, `my_field` would successfully use `field__custom_entity.html.twig` but would ignore `field__custom_entity__my_field.html.twig`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to place the least specific suggestion at the beginning of the array so that the more specific suggestions have priority. See the edit.

Comment: I unfortunately was not able to get this to work, despite array_unshift. I ended just creating templates specific to each field.